# How to ask good questions?

Tags: discussion

**How can I ask better questions?**

As I looked at the site stats, I noticed that many questions go unanswered. I believe that this is the fault of the questions.

Some links that have helped myself:

1. [How can I get answers fast?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8010/210573)
2. [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/210573)
3. [How can I improve my questions to regain the ability to ask questions on StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167888/210573)

Comment: Perhaps the second part of your question should be an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer to the question is in the question.